# Get number of rows in a result set?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am currently using the following way to access the content of a resultset from a prepared statement

```
std::string SQL = "....";
prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement(SQL);
res = prep_stmt->executeQuery();
if(res->next()) //If object exists
{
    res->getString("ColumnName"); //Access the content of a column
}
```

Is there any way for me to access the rows in a result set in advance before `res->next()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

give a try to the rowsCount() method

```
cout << "Number of rows : " << res->rowsCount() << endl;
```

Edit: Notice rowsCount returns a size_t

Answer (score 3):

```
Result = mysql_store_result( Connection );
if (Result) {
    RowsReturned = mysql_num_rows( Result );
} else {
    RowsReturned = 0;
}
```

[See this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696009/mysql-num-rows-segfaults) (It's where I shamelessly copied the code from (a).

Comment: I cant seem to access `mysql_num_rows`